# Why does `matlabpool` under ssh need X forwarding?

Tags: ssh, parallel-processing, x11, matlab

I just encountered and circumvented a problem in Matlab, but I'm still wondering why this happens, and I also want to leave the information here for future reference.

In Matlab's *Parallel Computing Toolbox*, the command `matlabpool local` starts a local pool of Matlab workers which are then used transparently to speed up commands like `parfor` by distributing processing onto the different CPU cores. I tried to do so on a Linux machine which I connected to through ssh from my home Linux computer. I used ssh without X forwarding because the script I wanted to run only computes and saves the result, but does not produce graphical output.

The problem: `matlabpool` hung forever, without any indication of the cause. I restarted the remote machine, restarted Matlab, checked for license problems, without result.

The problem was resolved however when I closed ssh and logged back in, this time including the `-X` option for X11 forwarding – even though then I started Matlab with the `-nodesktop` option.

Does anyone have an idea why `matlabpool` on Linux appears to depend on access to X11?

Comment: This is definitely not expected. I just tried here using R2014a on GLNXA64 machine and was able to launch a `matlabpool` (or `parpool` as it's now called) successfully. What version of MATLAB are you using?

Comment: @Edric, my version is 2013a. I'll try and see whether I can get an update.

Comment: Very strange - I just tried R2013a and everything worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Even though `matlabpool` starts and communicates with background **headless** workers, you can still create figures and plots and print/export them as images inside the `parfor` parallel loop. The following is a valid use case:

```
matlabpool(..)
parfor i=1:4
    plot(..)
    print(...)
    close(..)
end
```

<strike>To me this suggests that background workers will still depend on graphics capabilities to generate the invisible plots in memory (maybe it's using virtual framebuffers and such). Of course this is just speculation on my part :)</strike>

---

### EDIT:

Just to be sure here, can you try the following sequence of commands:

```
[client]$ ssh -v -x user@server    # X11 forwarding disabled

[server]$ unset DISPLAY            # clear $DISPLAY variable
[server]$ nohup matlab -nodesktop -nodisplay -noFigureWindows -nosplash \
                       -r "myscript; quit;" 2>&1 < /dev/null &
```

Where the script contains a simple parallel test like:

#### myscript.m

```
parpool('local',2)
smpd
    fprintf('hello from lab#%d', labindex);
end
delete(gcp('nocreate'))
```

If MATLAB still hangs, try adding the `-debug` start option:

> `matlab -debug` starts MATLAB and displays debugging information that can be useful, especially for X based problems.

Comment: Thanks or the speculation! :-) I don't believe that's the case though, because when I log in via ssh without X11 forwarding and start Matlab, I can without problem generate figures and export them. I can't *see* the figures, but in-memory they exist and exported graphics files contain what they are supposed to contain.

Comment: @A.Donda: looks like I was wrong, sorry! Can you try following the steps I posted and report back the outcome?

Comment: I'm afraid running that script doesn't work because my version of Matlab doesn't recognize either `parpool` or an `spmd ... end` block. I guess both is post-2013a? What I did though was use the shell commands and then the `nohup matlab` with `-r "matlabpool local 4; quit;"` – and it still hangs. Unfortunately, using `-debug` does not generate any messages about what might be the problem.